# Halt progress of Ninja Forms if Webhooks respond with error

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, ninja-forms

I'm setting up Ninja Forms in Wordpress. And I want to use the Webhooks extension to post a code to an external URL. If the code is correct Ninja Forms should submit the data on move on. If the code is wrong then the user should get an error message and try again.

How can I do this, I see no way if interrupting the submit?

Answer (score 0):

In Ninja Form when you use webhook, I guess you may catch the error respond from the API with this code

```
$data['errors']['form'][] = $this->submit_response->result[0]->error;
```

So when the API respond error, in this case user has no chance to re-submit the form again unless reload the page.
When the form contain the error, Ninja form prevent the form to submit, so you need to find a way to clear/remove this error.
Few workarounds can fix this problem.

An easy way is that, you cache the respond error differently with the following code:

```
$data['errors']['last']['message'] = $this->submit_response->result[0]->error;
```

With this code, your form will not display the error message respond from API but it is possible for user to re-submit the form again and you can use the javascript code below to display the error to some HTML element

```js
var customFormController = Marionette.Object.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Listen to submit respond
        this.listenTo(nfRadio.channel( 'forms' ), 'submit:response', this.checkSubmitRespond);
    },
    checkSubmitRespond: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR, formID) {
        if ('undefined' != typeof response.errors.last) {
            var msg = response.errors.last.message;
            // display error on some pre-defined element
            jQuery('.error-container').html(msg);
        }
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    new customFormController();
});
```

Hope this help.